# Animate a changing prop on a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I've written a pure React function of the form:

```
export function MyReactFunction(props) {

  return (<div>{props.myValue}</div>)
}
```

What I want to do is get the `<div>` to flash every time `props.myValue` is updated.

I'm trying to do this with `react-transition-group`, but I'm not sure what the right approach is.

No need to code a solution, but if you can help explain which way I should go, that would be a great help!

Thank you!